# Unable to install specific version of go on mac with homebrew

Tags: go, homebrew

i am trying to install go lang version 1.12.7 with

```
brew install go@1.12.7
```

but its saying formula is wrong.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you install 1.12.7 while 1.12.9 is current you are doing it wrong anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "simple way".

By default `brew` allows you set only last *patch* version for go1.12, because of [formula file](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/df2816f89ba3afca571c737f674dba0476748593/Formula/go.rb) (right now it is 1.12.9).

But you can do it manually.

```
:~$ cd "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)"
:~$ git log --oneline Formula/go.rb # To see all old versions
:~$ git reset --hard go1.12.7
HEAD is now at fa46027fe go: update 1.12.7 bottle.

:~$ HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install go@1.12
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/go-1.12.7.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
```